# Rails date loss of precision

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I have an annoying issue with Rails/Active Record and dates that I'm trying to figure out. We're using date fields for composite keys, which I am turning into timestamps to make it easier for use as URL parameters. This is working fine, but I have inconsistencies when trying to lookup records after converting the timestamp back into a DateTime. When the object is serialised, the ID sent back looks something like `1401810373.197,63` where the first number is the timestamp with milliseconds, and the second value is the original ID that rails normally uses.

When a request is received with this ID, the timestamp is parsed using the following

```
... get timestamp from input ...
Time.at(Rational(timestamp)).utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N')
```

This works as expected, and the queries produced using this also work as expected. The issue lies in that the date time produced here, is slightly different to the one on the original object. They're out by something like `1ms` which I'm assuming is due to the loss of precision when using `to_f` to get the timestamp.

I did a quick test in a console with the following code to replicate it

```
Model.all.each do |m|
  puts Time.at(Rational("#{m.to_param.split(',').first}")).utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N') == m.created_at.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N')
end
```

The output of this shows multiple `true` and `false` values, so something is definitely going wrong in the conversion.

Currently, the `to_param` method simply converts the `created_at` field using `to_f`. I've tried changing this to `"%.6f" % m.created_at.to_f` but this hasn't changed anything.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this difference in times, as it's causing an array of issues.

This is currently running on Postgres, where the `created_at` column is a `timestamp(3)` column. We're using `Rails 4.1` with `jRuby 1.7.12`

Comment: Timestamps should not be used as keys. Internally there is always a precision problem as they are basically float values, and not all timestamp values can be represented perfectly as floats. That said, in Postgres you do have some control on timestamp precision... like defining the column timestamp(6) instead of timestamp(3).

Comment: @Frazz: From the manual: "Floating-point datetime storage was the default in PostgreSQL releases prior to 8.4, but it is now deprecated, because it does not support microsecond precision for the full range of timestamp values.". By default it now uses a 64-bit integer type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up dropping the accuracy entirely. Now the database has a type of `timestamp(0)` and rails has been modified to not provide the milliseconds. Seems to be working :)